# Could not load file or assembly 'Sybase.AdoNet2.AseCient'

Tags: asp.net, database-connection, sybase

My .Net application is using `Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient.dll` version `2.157.1330.0` and it works fine on Dev environment. But on production environment, version `2.157.1360.0` is installed in GAC.

Now the same app doesn't work on Prod because of this and I am getting error `Could not load file or assembly 'Sybase.AdoNet2.AseCient'`

I was under the impression that the version available is higher one then it should work but it is not working. Even the difference between versions is just minor one. Is there something I need to do in my app or in production environment to make it work?